# Different packet sizes on Wi-Fi and 3G interfaces while tethering

Tags: forwarding, tcpdump, 3g

I am using an application called `android-wifi-tether` on a mobile phone. My laptop is connected to the phone over Wi-Fi and the phone is connected to Internet over 3G.

I am using `tcpdump` to sniff both Wi-Fi and 3g interfaces to do some analysis on forwarded packets. I realized that the frame sizes captured on 3G interface are always 2 bytes more than the frames on Wi-Fi interface. What can be the reason of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out these additional 2 bytes are because of Linux cooked-mode capture (SLL) which constructs a fake link-layer header. More detailed info can be found [here](http://www.wireshark.org/lists/ethereal-users/200412/msg00314.html)

Answer (score 2):

The MTU is defined per media protocol, and in the case of wireless networks leave a lot of leeway to the specific implementation. This is because a large MTU facilitates quicker transfer of a given amount data due to lower combined overhead, whilst also rapidly loosing in efficiency vs a small MTU if the link is poor and data often has to be retransmitted. The packet size can be chosen with that in mind: a good connection can benefit from larger packet sizes, a poor connection from smaller.

Wireless exists in a lot of variants, I won't even try to list them, but will note that the 3G variants are based on different protocol specifications than the Wifi protocol specs.

This (more than anything else) would explain any differences in packet sizes between your 3G and Wifi interfaces.

Just as tidbits:

- [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3481#section-4.4) is an rfc defining at least two 3G specifications.
- [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009) is the wikipedia article detailing the 802.11n(2009) protocol.